# How to loop a number’s digits with odd powers in C?

Tags: c

I’m new to C, and I need to take an integer user input and increment its alternating digits by odd powers of 10 **without using arrays**. For example, if the user types **4**9**0**6, I have to increment 0 and 4 by 1/10^1 and 1/10^3.

```
// Extracting alternating digits (User input e.g. 4906 stored in long number)

(number / 10) % 10;     // pow(10,1)
(number / 1000) % 10;   // pow(10,3)
(number / 100000) % 10; // pow(10,5)
```

I do not know the size of the long the user will type in, therefore, I need to loop alternating digits of this number by (1 / odd powers of 10) % 10.

Thank you so much.

Comment: What if the user inputs 9090?

Comment: Why `1/10^3` and not `10^3`?

Comment: I would need 9 and 9. For the first 9, I would divide the number by 10 and then do % 10. For the second 9, I would divide the same number by 1000 and then do % 10. I do not know how to loop this. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Use the `log10()` function to find out how many digits there are. That will tell where to start processing the digits.

Comment: increment? extract? ... what do you really want? "Luhn's" algorithm maybe? :-)

Comment: Yup, Luhn’s algorithm (without arrays)! Sorry I don’t know a lot of terms since I’m new to C and I’m not a native English speaker.

Comment: I wrote this for one of your "colleagues" a couple days ago: https://ideone.com/OESldI

Comment: why not just adding `1010` ?  What happens if one adding sums to 10?  do carries work or shouldn't they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//step 1
4906 % 10 = 6
4906 / 10 = 490

//step 2
490 % 10 = 0
490 / 10 = 49

//step 3
49 % 10 = 9
49 / 10 = 4

//step 4
4 % 10 = 4
4 / 10 = 0

//step 5 (last, after that you get only zeros)
0 % 10 = 0
0 / 10 = 0
```

As you can see, no **array** and **length** information needed. Just **mod** and **divide** (by ten) inside a loop until you hit **zero**.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    i  = 4906;         /* this is the sample number you used in the question */
    i += 1010;         /* this is the number to add to it. */
    printf("%d\n", i); /* this is the resulting value */
}
```